# ModuleNotFoundException youtube-dl module is not recognized

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

i have installed the youtube-dl module via pip with `pip install youtube-dl` and it worked. I can use it in CMD but for some weird Reason Python says that the Module doesnt exist:

```
Extension 'cogs.music' raised an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'
```

Comment: You have tagged your question `python` and `python3`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this problem usually happens when there is more than one python version on the computer, download the modules according to the version you want to use**

if this is didn't work for us do like bottom steps

go your python libs path and look up you must got this ........\lib\site-packages\youtube-dl

if you havn't got, go pypi site and download [packets](https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/#files)

after that, take out this file to  ......\lib\site-packages
you should see like this :[image]

or you can do like this:go your python path and open cmd and start writing:

```
......\python.exe -m pip install youtube_dl
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import youtube_dl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'youtube_dl'

Comment: In the Python Directory there is only Python 3.8

Comment: oh man, i have no idea anymore i will do some more research for now i will change my answer if i find something

Comment: mate, i realized a think if you got a only python version your downloaded packages will be same path, can you look up? this will be like this lib\site-packages\youtube-dl

Comment: Sooo i looked and the packages are both there...xD The really weird thing is, when i type "pip list" it shows me that youtube_dl is there xD The Interpreter is set to the right Python Version etc xD

Comment: Edit: I realized that there is another Python Interpreter available, but its the Windows Version. The weird thing is that i have never downloaded this version...xD How can i delete it? Maybe that is the Problem

Comment: I think i found the Problem...The wrong interpreter is being used...Its not using the one from python.org. Its using the stupid windows version                                                                Update: I have deleted the Windows Version and now i cant exicute python scripts at all because Visual Studio Code doesnt want to use the other Interpreter

Comment: Soooo after another intensive google session it worked xD But now i have to type only "python" and not "python3" xD i mean python --version tells me the correct version so fine by me xD Thanks for all your help!

Comment: no matter, i knew you got 2 verison, glad you solved the problem, good luck:)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following command.

```
pip3 install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Comment: Already tried xD When i upgrade it tells me this: Requirement already up-to-date: youtube-dl in c:\users\4tl4s\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (2020.9.20)